# 18.04: Can't mount or unmount external HDD "An operation is already pending",

Tags: mount, hard-drive

There are a lot of the same questions out there, but I still cant get my hard drive to mount. Let me give you the backstory - maybe there are some details I'm not savvy to that I need to include in my searches.

I have a dell r510 with Ubuntu 18.04 desktop on it. I have a 8 tb external HDD. This hard drive was mounted just fine, and I tried to download ~300gb of files via an FTP protocol using filezilla to this drive. All files had an error saying the location on the drive couldn't be found, and that all files I tried to download had failed. No big deal, I figured I'd retype the drive location and try again. This time, I couldn't access the hard drive at all.

The drive appears in the margin of my file manager, but when I double click on it, I get "Unable to access 'external2' An operation is already pending". When I try to unmount it by right clicking, I get "Unable to stop 'Seagate Desktop' Error opening /dev/sde: Device or resource busy". When I try to mount it by right clicking, I get "unable to access 'external2' and operation is already pending". I tried to sudo umnout the drive but the drive apparently doesn't exist. I have the same issues, the drive not existing that is, when I try to locate it using sudo fdisk and trying to see what processes are running on it using fuser.

I guess what I'm saying is I don't how to identify the processes or operations running on a drive I can't access that doesn't appear to be mounted.

Help?

```
sudo mount | sudo grep /dev/sde, sudo lsof +D /dev/sde, fuser /dev/sde
[sudo] password for: 
grep: sudo: No such file or directory
grep: lsof: No such file or directory
grep: +D: No such file or directory
grep: /dev/sde,: No such file or directory
grep: fuser: No such file or directory
```

This is in spite of /dev/sde being mounted.

Comment: `mount | grep /dev/sde`, `sudo lsof +D /dev/sde`,`fuser /dev/sde`

Comment: @waltinator Didn't work. See outputs above.